# Running JavaScript in an iframe on the parent webpage

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe

I have a web page that I need a countdown timer on, but the countdown timer's JavaScript code is generated in an `iframe` alongside other page content. I need to push this content into the parent frame with Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('contentarea').innerHTML = 
    "Please Wait... Countdown is loading FOO";
```

And part of the FOO is a countdown code...

```
<script>
var upgradeTime = 186000; //no of seconds
var seconds = upgradeTime;
function timer() {
    var days = Math.floor(seconds/24/60/60);
}
//The Code doesn't end here but let me not bore anyone
</script>
```

How do I achieve this so that the injected JavaScript code will run on the parent page?

Comment: If using the same origin, you can use `parent`, but it sounds like you should just use a `script` tag and ditch the `iframe` entirely.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara They said they are loading content in the `iframe` as well.

Comment: @4castle You can also load content with JavaScript, however this question and the exact problem is very unclear.

Comment: Keep in mind that this won't work if the `iframe` is referencing a different domain or HTTP protocol. It will trigger a security error thinking it is XSS.

Comment: They are both from the same domain @4castle

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara the iframe is needed because I generate content with PHP in it, and the content is refreshed every once in a while as required. Whenever it is ready, I write it into a <div> in the parent web page which is in the same domain with the iframe. However, the content which is written into the parent page could have a countdown timer that will display on the parent page, and this countdown timer has a javascript code that must be written into a DIV in the parent page.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`window.parent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/parent) in the `iframe`'s JavaScript.

```
parent.document.getElementById('contentarea').innerHTML = 
    "Please Wait... Countdown is loading FOO";
```

Comment: Yes, appending parent will work, but that's not the actual problem. The issue here is replacing FOO with a javascript code that will run on the parent page. Thank you

Comment: @Ekene What would be an example of the expected HTML output? Essentially, all of the output statements would be the same (as if you were modifying the current page), but with `parent` in front of it.

Comment: the expected output should look like this: `code` Please Wait... Countdown is loading <script>
var upgradeTime = 186000; //no of seconds
var seconds = upgradeTime;
function timer() {
    var days = Math.floor(seconds/24/60/60);
}
//The Code doesn't end here but let me not bore anyone
</script>`code`

Comment: There's no need to put the <script> in the parent window. Like I said, keep the JavaScript you want to execute in the iframe, but in the iframe JS, just put `parent` in front of all of the output statements. What is the output of your JS?